# Parse Error with Wordpress Template - broke my site

Tags: php, wordpress, parse-error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /home/content/90/12894990/html/wp-content/plugins/levelup-core/admin/metaboxes/config-meta-boxes.php
>   on line 261

I downloaded and opened the file in Dreamweaver and it's telling me there's actually a syntax error on line 521 which is:

```
'visible' => [$prefix . 'header_transparent', 'in', [1]]
```

can anyone help me with this? Cause it's made the entire wordpress site inaccessible, kinda driving me nuts.

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a PHP version before [version 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), in which the short array syntax was added.

New features introduced include:

```
Short array syntax has been added, e.g. $a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; or $a = ['one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'four' => 4];.
```

Answer (score 0):

To really solve this problem i need a bigger piece of code. But it seems like a wrong declaration of an array. In the line you posted replace the block quotes for proper quotation:

```
'visible' => $prefix . 'header_transparent', 'in', 1
```

Might not solve the entire problem, but its the best i can do with just this line.

Comment: My dude, you fixed it! I can't thank you enough!